# Kubernetes service externalTrafficPolicy reset to Local

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, greenplum

In my Kubernetes cluster setup, I have a Greenplum DB cluster (one master and 8 segments nodes) with a LoadBlanacer service. Please refer to the below service config.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: greenplum
    greenplum-cluster: greenplum-cluster
  name: greenplum
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.101.251.127
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.101.251.127
  externalIPs:
  - 11.4.8.141
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  healthCheckNodePort: 32572
  ports:
  - name: psql
    nodePort: 32198
    port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: master-0
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

However, a few hours after deployment, the `externalTrafficPolicy` value is set to `Local` instead of `Cluster`, which made the service inaccessible via the defined external IP. Is there any reason for this? It changes automatically even after I edit the service configuration.

Or is there any other way to access this Greenplum DB (TCP 5432) such as ingress?

Comment: Could you please describe what K8s cluster environment you are using - version, cloud/ bare metal?

Comment: This is kubeadm setup

Comment: How exactly it is configured? What's the version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on your Kubernetes cluster setup? Is this bare-metal, cloud managed, kubeadm?

Would be useful to see the logs when you try to connect to the DB, also some traces?

The only difference between externalTrafficPolicy `Local` or `Cluster` is that `Cluster` will balance the traffic between all pods in the cluster having a nice distribution between your pods. `Local` will only distribute the traffic between the pods already deployed on the node where the request land from the LB.

Additionally using `Local` will [preserve the clientIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) of the request but not the `Cluster` option.

There is a nice video who really explain this on detail [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2bhV81MfKQ&t=1823s).